# Autohotkey not finding Runwait command

Tags: windows, batch-file, autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotKey with some simple commands using Runwait and Copy.  Recently my scripts started failing in the command prompt with "'Runwait' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'.  I can't seem to figure out if this executable is a Windows batch command or an Autokey utility.  Re-installing Autokey did not help.  Can anybody tell me where this application resides and how I might restore it?

Thanks

Comment: `Runwait` is an AutoHotkey or AutoIt command. Don't know whether it's an external utility. Make sure the AutoHotkey is runnig. Check the `PATH` environment variable. Where `Runwait` resides? Do a windows search...

Comment: I've searched my entire drive, and there is no runwait.  AutoHotKey is in the path.  I'm hoping someone can search their drive and tell me where it is supposed to reside.

Comment: Can you post your code, please?  Or perhaps a screenshot of the error box?

Comment: Check @bizz-keryear answer, looks like you're getting this message because you're trying to use Runwait in a batch script (.cmd or .bat) instead of AutoHotkey script (.ahk) [this is just a guess based on the error message you posted]

Answer (score 1):

Runwait is a command build within autohotkey and only works with in AHK-scripts.

You can't use it in batch files.

But you can use it to run batch files.

`runwait mybatch.bat` in an AHK-script would cause the batch "mybatch.bat" to run and to wait until it is done.